# How to pass data to CActiveForm

Tags: yii

I have a form with dropDownList
I need to pass the data from DB to that list.

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'parent',$dd_data); ?>
```

Where and how should I define $dd_data array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CHtml::listData](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) to populate `$dd_data`, directly in the view, or use it in the controller and pass it to the view.

`$dd_data` array needs to be of format: `array('value'=>'display')` check [CHtml::dropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail).